# How to send arbitary, optional keyword arguments along with a post_save signal in django

Tags: python, django-models, django-signals

I'm using the "classic" method of extending a base User model (authentication details only) with a one-to-one relationship with a UserProfile model, along with a post_save signal to create UserProfile along with User, like so:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False,blank=False, verbose_name='email')
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='staff status')
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='active status')
    date_joined=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,verbose_name='join data')
    groups=models.ManyToManyField(Group , verbose_name='users group')
    user_permissions=models.ManyToManyField(Permission, verbose_name='user permission')
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=[]
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD='email'
    objects=UserManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email.split('@')[0]
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', verbose_name='first name')
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='',verbose_name='middle name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='',verbose_name='last name')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.RESTRICT ,verbose_name='linked auth user model')
    organization=models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',verbose_name='parent organization')
    profile_pic = models.ImageField()
    #etc etc
```

The following signal works as expected:

```
@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=User)
def userProfileLinker(sender,instance, created, **kwargs):
   del kwargs['signal']
   if created:
       UserProfile.objects.create( user = instance, **kwargs)
   return None
```

I would like to take this a litle bit further by [optionally passing] values for additional fields for UserProfile i.e. `User.objects.create_user(email='bogus@email.com',password='123456', first_name = 'Julia')` and have these values i.e. first_name get set to UserProfile, else use the defaults. I have the following manager for User:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Email is required'))

        if not password:
            raise ValueError(_('Password is required'))
        
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is False:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff set to True'))
        
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is False:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser set to True'))

        return self.create_user(email,password,**extra_fields)
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending an absurd amount of time on this, I found a solution:

```
#Define a custom post_save signal
saveSignal = Signal()

#Define a a receiver
@receiver(saveSignal)
def afterSave(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    #Need to enforce a created clause here
    #kwargs are now the optional parameters sent on save
    fields = kwargs['parameters']
    UserProfile.objects.create(**fields, user=instance)
    #Everything not explicitly provided assumes default values
    return None


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self,email,password,**extra_fields)
    # [...]
    
    #Capture optional arguments as xs_fields
    user.save(using=self._db, xs_fields = extra_fields)
    return user
```

Override the base model (User) save method to manually send a post save signal:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       # Collect all optional arguments and forward everything else to save
       fields = kwargs['xs_fields']
       del kwargs['xs_fields']
       # Save the User
       super().save(*args, *kwargs)

    #Dispatch the signal after save, along with collected data

    saveSignal.send(sender=User, instance = self ,parameters=fields)

    return None
```

This has some problems though. It doesn't seem to work if placed in a sepperate signals.py file, per docs reccomendations. Trying to follow instructions there results in ready() not being called for some reason and the signal fails. It's also laking a created clause